# ORA-01722: invalid number when executing query through pro*C

Tags: oracle

I am facing ORA-1772: invalid number again and again when the query is run through pro*c file. Same query works fine when executed directly on pl/sql developer.

```
SELECT queue_entry_id ,queue_urgency,
 TO_CHAR (chg_dt, 'MM-DD-YY'),
 TO_CHAR (queue_after_dt, 'MM-DD-YY'),
 chg_who ,
 upd_cnt FROM BSD_QUEUE_WORK WHERE queue_entry_id IN (
 SELECT queue_entry_id FROM (
 SELECT  /*+ INDEX (bsd_queue_work bsd_q_wrk_dt_idx) */ 
 BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_entry_id 
  FROM BSD_QUEUE_WORK WHERE  BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt <= SYSDATE
  order by BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_urgency DESC, BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt) 
  WHERE rownum <=20) FOR UPDATE;
```

Old query looked like -

```
SELECT
  /*+  INDEX (bsd_queue_work bsd_q_wrk_dt_idx)  +*/
  BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_entry_id,
  TO_CHAR(BSD_QUEUE_WORK.chg_dt,:b0) ,
  TO_CHAR( BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt,:b0) ,
  BSD_QUEUE_WORK.chg_who ,
  BSD_QUEUE_WORK.upd_cnt
FROM BSD_QUEUE_WORK
WHERE (BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt<=SYSDATE
AND ROWNUM                          <=:b2)
ORDER BY BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_urgency DESC BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt FOR UPDATE
```

This query was first selecting 20 rows and then sorting them on queue_urgency. This lead to high urgency rows waiting long for their turn if we had total of 10k rows. And, User wanted to find out high queue_urgency rows first and process them in chunks of 20 rows. Hence, I created the new query which is giving errors as above.

Table structure is as-

```
SQL> desc bsd_queue_work


Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 QUEUE_ENTRY_ID                            NOT NULL NUMBER(18)
 QUEUE_AFTER_DT                            NOT NULL DATE
 UPD_CNT                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 CHG_WHO                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 CHG_DT                                    NOT NULL DATE
 QUEUE_URGENCY                             NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
```

Comment: Well, you don't show us any of the pro*c code, so how can we help you?

Comment: Perhaps, some other query in your code should be causing this! You handle the `sqlca` structure for every query you run ? Also make sure, you connect to the same database through `Pro*C` and `PL/SQL Developer`.

Comment: Hi, Earlier query looked like -         select  /*+  INDEX (bsd_queue_work bsd_q_wrk_dt_idx)  +*/
BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_entry_id ,TO_CHAR(BSD_QUEUE_WORK.chg_dt,:b0) ,TO_CHAR(
BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt,:b0) ,BSD_QUEUE_WORK.chg_who ,
BSD_QUEUE_WORK.upd_cnt  from BSD_QUEUE_WORK where (
BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt<=SYSDATE and ROWNUM<=:b2)
order by BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_urgency desc ,BSD_QUEUE_WORK.queue_after_dt  for update  ;  it worked correctly but chose first 20 rows first and then sorted them acc to priority

Comment: @OldProgrammer; @Maheshwaran Ravisankar

yes i connected the same DB

Comment: .pc file just has this query in the desired function and required format for the connection and execution. Query was running fine before any modification

Comment: Kindly edit your question and add the older Query.

Comment: @Maheswaran Ravisankar 
Hi, I have edited my main question and added old query too

Comment: is queue_urgency really a 38 digit number?

Comment: No it varies from 1 to 10